# Get the Pid of the background process executed using bash -c

Tags: bash, shell

I need to execute a program in background, and the program should keep on running, after the shell execute.
I am executing the script using `nohup` and using `bash -c` to make it run in background.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/go/src/github.com/something && pwd && bash -c  "nohup go run apps/something/main.go >> /var/logs/go/crash.log 2>&1 &"
```

I need to get the pid of the `nohup` command executed in the spawned shell using `bash -c`, I tried using

```
 cd /mnt/go/src/github.com/something && pwd && bash -c  "nohup go run 
apps/something/main.go >> /var/logs/go/crash.log 2>&1 & echo $! > /var/run/something.pid"
```

But the output is empty string, is there any better way to solve this issue.
Because of using `bash -c` I cannot get the PID using `$?`.

Comment: If i don't use `bash -c` then I can do it, but I am using `bash -c`, as otherwise there will be more than 2 processes running, one for the script and one for the executed command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Why are you chaining everything with `&&`? If you want to stop the script if an error occurs, just add `set -e` below the shebang. It makes sure that the script stops executing if a command returns an exit status not equal to 0</strike>. Don't use `set -e` (read link in comments).

As I've wrongly commented in a previous edit, it seems that your code should be valid in the first place (thx @tripleee).

I think the error occurs because you use `"` instead of `'`. The error occurs because Bash first has to parse the string to replace variables. Since the current shell hasn't created a child process, `$!` is empty and therefore your file as well. Try it with an single quote:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /mnt/go/src/github.com/something
pwd
bash -c  'nohup go run apps/something/main.go >> /var/logs/go/crash.log 2>&1 & echo $! > /var/run/something.pid'
cat /var/run/something.pid
```

Comment: `&` is a valid command separator; there is no requirement to have a newline before the `echo`.

Comment: I can't believe that all this time I've been writing bash scripts, I never figured out that '&' is a valid command separator on itself. Thanks @tripleee!

Comment: without using `set -e`